# seems like append() adds the variables and not their values

Tags: python, python-2.7, append

I am reading a CSV file that has "missing" index values (e.g., 1, 2, 4 -- missing the 3rd index). I want to fill in the blanks with dummy lines that have the index and zeros for other variables. This is the code that fills in the blanks (the print function is for inspection):

```
for i in range(int(row[0]) - id_last - 1):
    dummy_row[0] = i
    print dummy_row
    csv_raw.append(dummy_row)
```

The print output shows the rows as intended. But in the csv_raw, all the values in the 1st column (the index) are equal to the last value of i and not to the i in the moment in which I called the append function. Here is the output:

print dummy_row:

> [3, 0, 0] [4, 0, 0] [6, 0, 0] [7, 0, 0] [8, 0, 0] [9, 0, 0]

print csv_raw (at the end of the program):

> [[1, '1st', '1'], [2, '2nd', '2'], [9, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0], [5, '3rd',
>   '3'], [9, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0], [9, 0, 0], [10, '4th', '4']]

I've tried to declare that goes up after each loop, but it did not changed the result. I would like to understand how to fix the problem and why it happens. I guess that this is related to the way that python works (I know some basic C, but no formal training in python).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `csv_raw.append(dummy_row)`, you aren't appending a copy of `dummy_row`. This means that you're adding a reference to the exact same object each time - and whenever `dummy_row` changes, the corresponding entry in `csv_raw` changes as well, because it's all the same.

What you want is to append a copy of `dummy_row` to `csv_raw`. Try this: `csv_raw.append(list(dummy_row))`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the super-fast answer. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
csv_raw.append(dummy_row[:])
```

to append a  full slice (which produces a shallow copy) of `dummy_row` to `csv_raw`. Currently, you are just putting references to **the same list** into your list `csv_raw`.

Demo of what is happening:

```
>>> master = []
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> master.append(a)
>>> master.append(a)
>>> master
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> a[1] = 42
>>> master
[[1, 42, 3], [1, 42, 3]]
```

`master` contains two references to `a`, so after changing `a`, the output for displaying `master` will change as well.

```
>>> master.append(a[:]) # append a COPY of a
>>> master
[[1, 42, 3], [1, 42, 3], [1, 42, 3]]
>>> a[1] = 100
>>> master
[[1, 100, 3], [1, 100, 3], [1, 42, 3]]
```

Now, `master[0]` and `master[1]` contain a reference the same object, which is a different object than `master[2]`.

```
>>> id(master[0])
41583032
>>> id(master[1])
41583032
>>> id(master[2])
41713816
```

Comment: Great play-by-play of what's happening in cases like this.